# update + push support in spark-mongodb library?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to inserting a new entry in embedded field in existing document in mongodb using spark.

**Example**

```
Blog {  
    id:"001"  
    title:"This is a test blog",  
    content:"...."  
    comments:[{title:"comment1",content:".."},{title:"comment2",content:"..."}]      
}
```

**What I want to do**

```
db.blogs.update({id:"001"}, {$push:{comments:{title:"commentX",content:".."}}});
```

Is it possible currently in this library? If not, can you please point me to the right direction.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do the operation I wished using the Casbah Library for Spark-mongoDb.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.util.Date

import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject
import com.mongodb.casbah.query.Imports._

object TestCasbah {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val mongoClient = MongoClient("172.18.96.45", 27017)
    val db = mongoClient("agentCallRecord")
    val coll = db("CallDetails")
    val query = MongoDBObject("agentId" -> "agent_1")
    val callRatingMongoObject = MongoDBObject("audioId" -> 12351,"startTime" -> new Timestamp(new Date().getTime).toString, "endTime" -> new Timestamp(new Date().getTime).toString, "totalScore" -> 1, "sentiment" -> "NEGATIVE")
    val update = $push("callRating" -> callRatingMongoObject)
    coll.update(query, update)
  }
}
```